# Answering mail to original poster as group

Tags: google-groups, google-workspace-for-business

Let me first describe the situation:

- We have a G Suite domain and groups for this domain
- The groups have an email address (e.g.: group@example.com)
- People outside the domain and not a member of this group can mail something to group@example.com. This will appear in the group and the members of the group will get an email with that message.

What we want to do is to be able to answer the mail the members get, so that the answer is added in the group and the original poster receives the answer as a mail from group@example.com.

The problem arises when we try to do just that:

- If we just hit reply we send a mail to the group => the original poster doesn't get the answer.
- If we hit reply all the answer will get posted to the group and the original poster will get the answer, **but** the mail to the original poster comes from the member (e.g. member@example.com) and not from group@example.com.

Would there be a solution to both put the answer in the group and send a mail to the original poster? This should be done in one action, and only via mail (not the webclient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This should be done in one action, and only via mail (not the webclient).

That bit makes it slightly more complicated.

If the replies from your domain were sent using the group webclient only, 
then you could enable 'Post As The Group' for selected users in Posting permissions.

But since you want it done via email, you'll have to use 'Send mail as'.

- https://support.google.com/a/answer/22370?hl=en
- https://support.google.com/a/answer/1710338?hl=en

A 3rd option would be to configure the group so that all emails appear as

```
From : "username" via "groupname" <groupaddress> 
Reply-To: "groupname" <groupaddress>
```